# Vue2: Why do I get infinite $http.get requests when I assign property from response?

Tags: ajax, vuejs2, vue.js, vue-resource

I make `$http.get` call to back-end where I process data and return a result, and I want to assign property to `this` dynamically (the property is declared in data list):

```
watch: {
    send_amount: function() {
        this.updateAmount('my_param1');
    },
    receive_amount: function() {
        this.updateAmount('my_param2');
    },
},

methods: {
    updateAmount: function(_par) {

        var vVar = this;

        this.$http.get('http://www.website.dev/api/calculate', { params: { rec: _par } })
                .then(function(response) {

                    _results = JSON.parse(response.data);

                    $.each(_results, function(k, v) {

                        vVar[k] = v; // << this causes the $http.get request to be sent over and over, infinitely.

                    });

                });
    }

}
```

Comment: Without seeing your data, I'd guesstimate you're updating the variable you're watching, causing the method to be called again and again.

Comment: That seems to have bee the problem. I have two inputs I'm watching, when either one is update by client the other one is update programmatically. I've update my code to illustrate it. So how can I make watch not to update in case of programmatic update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't want to call `updateAmount` method when the variables are changed programatically, You can instead remove the watch and use `v-on:change` in the input fields of these variables, like following:

```
<input v-model="receive_amount" v-on:change"updateAmount" />
```